# Android TimeStamp not working with ListView Adapter

Tags: php, android, json

Every time my **ListView** refreshes/reloaded the timestamp is always **Jan 17, 1970**. Why I always getting this?

My **timestamp** value

```
1441339200 = 2015-09-04
```

Code for timestamp

```
        CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                Long.parseLong(item.getTimeStamp()),
                System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
        timestamp.setText(timeAgo);
```

I think my code is wrong, if it's wrong how can I change it to make the **timestamp** value **1441339200** to it's **REAL DATE** value?

**Output must be String**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert your timestamp to milliseconds by multiplying it to 1000.

Comment: Long.parseLong(item.getTimeStamp()) * 1000 like this.

Comment: my bad the output is in ago but when i add new data its 2 hours ago even its now :( nvm my 1st comment